# Глобально изменить версию python

Tags: python, linux, django, debian, uwsgi

Здравствуйте!

Есть сервер с debian 8.5 , nginx, django 1.10, uwsgi, python (2.7, 3.4) всё это используется *без* vitrual env (venv). Есть сайт на django который сыпет ошибками

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0419' in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)
Request Method: GET
Django Version: 1.10.4
Exception Type: UnicodeEncodeError
Exception Value:    
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0419' in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/encoding.py in force_text, line 80
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/uwsgi-core
Python Version: 2.7.9
```

Ошибки из-за того, что в python там используется кириллица, а python2 не умеет её без указания codepages.

Вопрос: Как заставить запускаться всё это под python3.4 без использования virtualenv?
Доп. инфа:

```
[uwsgi]
PROJECT_NAME=%n
PROJECT_ROOT=/var/www/%(PROJECT_NAME)

chdir=%(PROJECT_ROOT)/src/
touch-reload=%(PROJECT_ROOT)/reload

module=core.wsgi
plugins=python3,http
master=true
workers=2
uid=www-data
gid=www-data
disable-logging=true
```

-

```
# update-alternatives --config python
Есть 2 варианта для альтернативы python (предоставляет /usr/bin/python).

  Выбор   Путь            Приор Состояние
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/python2.7   1         автоматический режим
  1            /usr/bin/python2.7   1         ручной режим
* 2            /usr/bin/python3.4   0         ручной режим
```

-

```
Fri Dec 30 14:31:39 2016 - *** Starting uWSGI 2.0.7-debian (64bit) on [Fri Dec 30 14:31:38 2016] ***
Fri Dec 30 14:31:39 2016 - compiled with version: 4.9.1 on 25 October 2014 19:17:54
Fri Dec 30 14:31:39 2016 - os: Linux-3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt25-2+deb8u3 (2016-07-02)
Fri Dec 30 14:31:39 2016 - machine: x86_64
Fri Dec 30 14:31:39 2016 - clock source: unix
Fri Dec 30 14:31:39 2016 - pcre jit disabled
Fri Dec 30 14:31:39 2016 - detected number of CPU cores: 2
Fri Dec 30 14:31:39 2016 - current working directory: /
Fri Dec 30 14:31:39 2016 - setgid() to 33
Fri Dec 30 14:31:39 2016 - setuid() to 33
Fri Dec 30 14:31:39 2016 - your processes number limit is 1912
Fri Dec 30 14:31:39 2016 - your memory page size is 4096 bytes
Fri Dec 30 14:31:39 2016 - detected max file descriptor number: 1024
Fri Dec 30 14:31:39 2016 - lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
Fri Dec 30 14:31:39 2016 - thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
Fri Dec 30 14:31:39 2016 - uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /run/uwsgi/app/pjreo.is74/socket fd 3
Fri Dec 30 14:31:39 2016 - Python version: 2.7.9 (default, Mar  1 2015, 13:01:26)  [GCC 4.9.2]
Fri Dec 30 14:31:40 2016 - *** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Fri Dec 30 14:31:40 2016 - Python main interpreter initialized at 0x257a410
Fri Dec 30 14:31:40 2016 - your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
Fri Dec 30 14:31:40 2016 - your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
Fri Dec 30 14:31:40 2016 - mapped 218304 bytes (213 KB) for 2 cores
Fri Dec 30 14:31:40 2016 - *** Operational MODE: preforking ***
Fri Dec 30 09:31:42 2016 - WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 2 seconds on interpreter 0x257a410 pid: 1095 (default app)
Fri Dec 30 09:31:42 2016 - *** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
Fri Dec 30 09:31:42 2016 - spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 1095)
Fri Dec 30 09:31:42 2016 - spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 1507, cores: 1)
Fri Dec 30 09:31:42 2016 - spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 1508, cores: 1)
```

Comment: а как django запускается?

Comment: Как модуль установленный через pip3: Django==1.10.4

Django-Select2==5.8.10

django-appconf==1.0.2

Comment: Глобальный python менять не следует (вы просто систему сломаете). Если вы не можете Django запустить в вашем окружении, то спрашивайте именно об этом. Сейчас вообще описание противоречит само себе (вы говорите что Django у вас для Питона 3 установлена,  но при этом показываете ошибки для Питона 2). Не ясно чем вызвана UnicodeEncodeError у вас (как Питон 2 так и 3 может такую ошибку получить). Запускайте Django именно на том Питоне, куда вы эту библиотеку ставили. Изолируйте UnicodeEncodeError и покажите минимальный но полный пример кода, который к ней ведёт. Покажите полный traceback.

Comment: @jfs в чём противоречие? Носом ткните пожалуйста. То что мне нужно запустить написано на python3, почему у меня окружение запускается с помощью python2 - _я понятия не имею_ и пытаюсь это узнать - собственно Вы можете увидеть это из вопроса. Никаких противоречий - это во-первых. Во-вторых ничего страшного не произойдёт от глобальной смены версии интерпритатора, просто надо учитывать это при установке новых пакетов и обновлении старых, это Вы клоните в совершенно иную тему, это никак не относится к вопросу, прошу не оффтопить.

Comment: Если кому-то интересно, помимо глобальной смены версии python (Привет @jfs) необходимо было ещё и сменить версию uwsgi о чём я понятия не имел (Уж простите, уважаемый, что сам не ответил сразу на свой вопрос) и разрешить зависимости модулей между python 2/3 (uwsgi-plugin-python3 как пример) и всё прекрасно заработало. Популярно: python, jango и иже с ними _вообще не при делах_, проблема была в том, что как в первом посте видно из логов, uwsgi использовал python2, а нужно было python3. Если хотите - можете записать это в отет.

Comment: Всё в одно сообщение не влезло. Имелось ввиду банально это: http://pastebin.com/uqzkpSuH

Comment: В домашней директории пользователя в файл .bashrc добавить строку alias python='/usr/bin/python3.4'. При условии что в системе питон 3 стоит